# Google Calendar API integration

Tags: google-calendar-api

My scenario is the following: We currently own an online rental marketplace that uses peer to peer bookings just like Airbnb. This means each user has a calendar for their property.We have a Vaway calendar for the bookings on our site however are wanting to integrate google calendar so we can be able to 2 way sync/asynchronous all the Ical calendars to each other from our partner sites who support it.

After much research I have tested my personal google calendar to see how the iCal works and it seems to work perfectly so we decided this architecture would need to be implemented on a much larger scale. This would be used in all new users signups to give our users an all in one calendar that syncs all our Partner sites into one completely synced google calendar for their listing. This basically allows a user who has their listing on 7 different platforms to sync to one calendar showing availability for them to keep track of inside Vaway account.

The google calendar would be completely separate from our Vaway calendar specifically to allow our users to sync all their property bookings from other sites into one integrated calendar.. The problem when reading about google calendar API is it requires OAuth 2.0 which is required user sign in from their existing google account (Calendar, Gmail...etc). Many of our users and new signups will not have google accounts and we do not want them to have to go through a google signup process to log into their calendar. Is there any way around OAuth 2.0? We really just need the functionality of the google calendar and its syncing capabilities inside our dashboard to give read write permission and sync back and forth 2 way with other calendars on other platforms.

With all of the features the google calendar has it seems to be perfect for what we are doing when testing. Each user that signs up with us will have google calendar in their Vaway dashboard provided by vaway however they will manage their own google calendar inside the Vaway platform for their property bookings. All calendars events/bookings would be public to allow the Ical syncing option to push through.

We do not want the users accessing this calendar outside of the platform because the pulls them away from the site. I'm not sure what solution would best suit this business model and am totally at my wits end here after researching. We are trying to keep our overhead low so google apps marketplace is not an option.

Comment: Paragraphs are your friend.  If you can make your question more readable, more people will want to read and answer it.

Comment: difficult to read bro..make it presentable

Comment: Made Adjustments please help!!:)

Answer (score 1):

You really should reformulate your question, because it's really hard to read and understand right now.

But if I really get your question, you want to enable managing google calendar from a personal application without the end user having to log to any google personal account.

If this is clearly what you want to do, I suggest you to have a look to Service Account with OAuth2.0.
(See here : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount)
It will provide a service account for your application, from which you will be able to handle calendars for your app.

And here you will find a sample showing how to do it with Java. (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts)